# Rails Engine Integration Questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

If I'm wanting to mount a particular Rails Engine within an application, does all code within that engine have to be compatible with the app on which the engine is being mounted?

For instance, if I have a Rails 5 app, and have an engine which uses Rails 4 code/Is a Rails 4 app, that engine would have to also be using Rails 5 or have compatible classes right?

Comment: Maybe it all depends on what "Rails 4 code" means. If you are using depreciated methods then warnings abound if you are using methods that were completely removed then yes it would need to be refactored. If you are using primarily pure ruby with basic rails syntax then it may survive for versions to come. All very dependent on your existing code base. In all cases you should try to make a homogeneous version if possible so as to avoid any current or future issues.

Comment: @engineersmnky got it. So just to double check, all the code in the engine would most definitely need to be compatible with all code within the app the engine is mounted on if I want them to be able to work together?

Comment: Also, sorry in this sense, Rails 4 code, meaning a Rails 4 app.

Comment: Yes otherwise you will run into dependency issues as things like `rails` would become ambiguous. That is why it is always best to (and you see pretty much every rails library) release version based engines for compatibility with each rails version. Refactor now means smaller refactoring when rails 5 becomes 6 or 7. IF you have ever tried to migrate an old app up more than 1 version you will understand the pain. Usually this is a uncomfortable stepping process e.g Rails 3 to rails 5 usually involves migrating to rails 4 patch and update and then migrate to rails 5 patch and update.

Comment: Thanks @engineersmnky, if you want to add an answer, I’ll accept it!

Comment: The differences between 4 & 5 are a lot smaller than between 3 & 4 though.